# How can I update a Network Manager connection from the command line?

Tags: command-line, networking, network-manager

I have a bunch of Ubuntu machines on my work ethernet LAN and I need to modify the default gateway.

I'd rather not traipse round, interrupt people's work, to right click an applet, preferring instead to ssh in, which can be automated :-)

I know I can change the default live gateway with `ip route replace default via 1.2.3.4` but this does not update NM's stored connection.

In my case each machine will only have one stored wired connection.

How can I update the stored gateway IP from the command line?

Comment: There's no easy way to do it using tools that Network Manager provides (at least, not in 14.04). You'll have to edit the appropriate file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`. Changes should be automatically detected and loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All configuration from Network Manager are in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

On this please you will find `Wired connection 1` witch is probably configuration file of you `lan` connection. You can edit it

`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1`

```
[802-3-ethernet]
duplex=full
mac-address=00:22:64:4E:6F:70

[connection]
id=Wired connection 1
uuid=57a2a340-c113-406f-9abc-eb816e58b3db
type=802-3-ethernet
timestamp=1430138708

[ipv6]
method=auto

[ipv4]
method=manual
dns=xxx.xxx.xxx.243;8.8.8.8;
dns-search=eunet.rs;
address1=xxx.xxx.47.5/24,xxx.xxx.47.254
```

You can change `ip`, `network mask` or `gateway`.
After change you made, save and restart `NM` with command

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I accepted 2707974's answer (great name) but here for anyone wanting to automate this stuff with a one-liner to change from `1.2.3.4` to `5.6.7.8`

```
sudo find /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ -type f -name "Wired*" \
 | while read c ; do sudo sed -i 's/1\.2\.3\.4/5.6.7.8/g' "$c" ; done ;  \
 sudo service network-manager restart
```

Of course this assumes that `1.2.3.4` is only found in the files in relation to the appropriate thing - so for me it was the default gateway and so the IP address only occurred once.

Comment: Better use `-exec`/`-execdir`: `sudo find /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ -type f -name "Wired*" -execdir sed -i 's/1\.2\.3\.4/5.6.7.8/g' {} + ;`