# Any command to set/update static IP address (no hack)?

Tags: command-line, network-manager

Unlike many threads, I see my on both 14.04 and 16.04 the NIC configs are stored in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`, which is still discussed on some threads but not many AFAI have seen. And I haven't found any tool-provided command. E.g. in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/615261/24203) someone gives a hint to update the ip address defined in an existing NIC config file (using `find`, `sed` etc.), but that's still a hack and there's no guarantee it'll still work once anything on the network manager or else on operating system changes.

Question: is there anyway to create / update files under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` from command line?

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 but info on newer distros is also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [nmcli](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/nmcli.1.html).

Show the available connections:

```
nmcli connection show
```

Show the current settings for connection with UUID `9fe88459-efaf-45bd-8958-ca1e202d04fd`:

```
nmcli connection show uuid 9fe88459-efaf-45bd-8958-ca1e202d04fd
```

Set the IPv4 address for this connection:

```
nmcli connection modify uuid 9fe88459-efaf-45bd-8958-ca1e202d04fd ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.5
```

Comment: As I just updated my question, I'm on 14.04 where [nmcli available](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/nmcli.1.html) is 0.9.8 that doesn't seem yet to have `modify` option. I still accept this as an answer for introducing `nmcli` that seems like is in the direction I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple goto terminal and type in:-

```
dhclient -r
```

This will let you drop your IP and get new from DHCP.
What this is a Dynamic host configuration protocol client. The internet systems consortium DHCP Client, dhclient, provides a means for configuring one or more network interfaces using Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol, BOOTP protocol, or if these protocols fail, by statically assigning an address.

Comment: Ok my OP wasn't clear (now title line updated for clarification) but I'm setting static IP, not dynamic.